# Simpe if and else in C programming

Tags: c, if-statement

I want to make this program say that if you enter 1 the screen will display "yes G is the 1st note in a G chord", if you enter anything else it will print "wrong!" and then loop back into the beginning, here is my attempt at it. Also, I know there are different ways to do this, but it is for a school assignment and the enum data-type is necessary, though this code is far reaching for just displaying use of enum, it bothers me I can't get this to work. Any pointers? (no pun intended).

```
enum Gchord{G=1,B,D,};
int main(){
    printf( "What interval is G in the G chord triad \nEnter 1 2 or 3\n" );  
    int note;
    scanf("%i",&note);    

    if (note = 1 ){                 
        printf ("Yes G is %ist note in the G-chord\n",G )};
    else(
        printf("no, wrong");     
    return(0):       
};
```

Comment: did you read up about loops yet?

Comment: you are assigning 1 to the variable `note` in you if condition.

Comment: Key problem: Insure your compiler has its warnings fully enabled or get a new compiler.  Good compilers would have warned you.  Saves you time.

Comment: LOL , I love it! you guys are such code snobs, I'm taking a computing methods class, and I wanted to see what errors I was making, I am still learning.  I'm currently using dev++ and its error warnings are very vague, but I'm comparing my mistakes everyone pointed out to the errors I'm getting, and I think I understand now. THANKS EVERYONE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a lot of problems in your code, but the main one is because you try to assign `1` to `note` instead of the comparission `==`.

Another thing is that you never check `scanf` for errors.

There are parentheses and brackets used wrong.

`int main(){}` shoudl be at least `int main(void){}`.

The `return` statement should be not treated as a function, there are no need of those parentheses around `(0)` and should end with a semicol `;` and not with `:`.

Now the following should explain you better what you probably tried to do:

```
#include<stdio.h>

enum Gchord{G=1,B,D,};

int main(void){
    printf( "What interval is G in the G chord triad \nEnter 1 2 or 3\n" );
    int note;

    if(scanf("%i",&note) == 1){
        if (note == 1 ){
            printf ("Yes G is %ist note in the G-chord\n",G );
        }else{
            printf("no, wrong");
        }
    }else{
        printf("Error, scanf\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`note = 1` is assigning `note` with the value `1`. You are looking to compare `note` with `1` and therefore you need the operator `==`. Read up on comparison operations here:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison

To be crystal clear:

```
note = 1;  // Assigning note to 1, note is now the value 1
note == 1; // Comparing note to 1, true if note is 1, false otherwise.
```

You also have plenty of other problems:

- In `printf ("Yes G is %ist note in the G-chord\n",G )};` Lines end with semicolons, if statements don't.
- `else(` else doesnt take an argument and should use a curly brace. `else {`
- `return(0)` Return is not a function.

Your compiler with warnings on full (`-Wall`) will tell you all of these things.  Things in the list above should have been compiler errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
I don't know where to start. Your code has a lot of errors.
```

- Code formatting: it is very important to learn how to format your code so it becomes easier to read it.
- `int note;` variables should almost always be declared at the top and also initialized (in this case with `int note = 0;`
- If you separate something with `,` enter a space behind it. not `scanf("%i",&note);` but `scanf("%i", &note);`
- To compare if 2 values are equal, use `==`. A single `=` is used to assign values to a variable. Wrong: `if (note = 1 )` Right: `if (note == 1)`
- You are using a wrong bracket for the `else` that you do not even close.
- And for your problem of looping, you should read up about `while loops` and ask again if you don't understand them.

  ```
  enum Gchord{G=1,B,D,};

  int main() {
      int note = 0;

      printf("What interval is G in the G chord triad \nEnter 1 2 or 3\n");         
      scanf("%i", &note);    
      if (note == 1) {                 
          printf ("Yes G is %ist note in the G-chord\n", G);
      }
      else {
          printf("no, wrong");
      }   
      return 0;       
  };
  ```

Comment: *a lot*, alot is not a word: http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html

Comment: @Michi i only did basic code formatting and correcting syntax errors to get him started and show how important it is to have code formatting

Answer (score 0):

There are a myriad of syntax errors in here including the one everyone has pointed out that note = 1 assigns a value of 1 to the note variable instead of testing for equality.  You want the == operator here.

Also you aren't really using the enum, your teacher probably wont pass you on this.

I modified your code a bit to make a little more use of the enum and to do the loop you are looking for.

```
enum Gchord { EXIT, G, B, D, };
int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        printf("What interval is G in the G chord triad \nEnter 1, 2, 3, or 0 to exit\n");
        Gchord note;
        scanf("%i", &note);

        if( note == EXIT )
            break;

        if (note == G)
            printf("Yes G is %ist note in the G-chord\n", G);
        else
            printf("no, wrong\n");
    }

    return(0);
};
```

Comment: Please at least check `scanf` for errors if you try to help.

Comment: Error checking and bullet proofing are obviously beyond the scope of the op's question.  Simple and clean is more helpful than convoluted and bulletproof.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the OP here. If you give an Answer, make it right.....if not leave a comment.

Comment: This answer is right. Just because you feel that someone should check for some error returns and handle possible cases that are outside the scope doesn't make that right. There are all sorts of ways to do all of this. If you wanted to really get into opinions of 'right' and 'wrong' code, perhaps you should post your own answer. Maybe not even use scanf at all, or maybe not even C!

Comment: Please review your code again. I don't have time for this, if you don't accept an advise...